# Jackson Serializing Enums And Non Traditional Setters/Getters

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson

I am trying to serialize a class which has an enum as one of its members. The setters and getters for the enum in the class I am trying to serialize do not follow the classic format. Below is an example of what I mean

```
public class myObj { 
    private StateEnum state;

    public String getState() { // Problem with this getter
        return state == null ? null : state.name();
    }

    public void setState(String state) { // Problem with this setter
        this.state = StateEnum.valueOf(state);
    }
}

public enum StateEnum implements Cloneable {
    ACTIVE("Active"), 
    PREPROCESS("Preprocessing"), 
    SELECT("Selecting");

    private final String description;

    EntityState(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "EntityState: " + this.description;
    }
```

}

Currently to serialize/deserialize I am using the something similar to the following.

```
myObj obj = new myObj();
ObjectMapper omap = new ObjectMapper();
String payload = omap.writeValueAsString(obj);
myObj deserializedObj = omap.readValue(obj);
```

And I get the error:
 `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Name is null`

How can I go about properly serializing/deserializing this without changing the setter and getter (adding @Json tags is okay)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with Jackson. It has to do with your setter not handling null correctly, and thus throwing an NullPointerException.

If you had read the full stack trace of the exception (and posted it, to avoid forcing us to guess the problem), you would have noticed it:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
    at com.foo.StateEnum.valueOf(StateEnum.java:3)
    at com.foo.MyObj.setState(MyObj.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.set(MethodProperty.java:113)
```

Replace it by

```
this.state = state == null ? null : StateEnum.valueOf(state);
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed it. The reason that I did not post the full stack trace is because I am actually doing something completely different from the example I posted above. The example is very oversimplified. This is an old code base and someone else wrote that setter/getter and I just assumed it worked. Good catch thanks again